# Convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: excel

I have the following dates on my Excel sheet.

```
02/01/2017
02/02/2017
02/03/2017
02/07/2017
2/15/2017
2/16/2017
```

I want it to read as Feb 1, Feb 2. etc however Excel reads the dates as January 2, 2017, Feb 02, 2017, March 02, 2017.

How do I do this? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built in function in Excel. Try from the ribbon above,

Number Group > More Number Formats > Date > Your desired Format

If you're looking for more customizability, try separating them by the / symbol using text to columns function from the Data tab in the ribbon.

This is what I got from punching in your data:

February 1, 2017

February 2, 2017

February 3, 2017

February 7, 2017

February 15, 2017

February 16, 2017

Comment: Hi, I tried the number format however it just interchanges the data. It would be 01/02/2017 but will still read as January 02, 2017.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Lets start over, say you have:  2/15/2017 . You want to make this into Feb 15, 2017, or Feb 15, or 2/15 ?

Comment: Hi, for example I have 02/01/2017. I want Excel to read it as February 01, 2017. In my Excel, it reads January 02, 2017.

Comment: Wat, why is it reading as January when the source is 2? Are you sure you selected the appropriate date number format from the options?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I've selected the appropriate date format. So when my date is 2/15/2017, it doesn't convert into long date anymore.

Comment: Okay, so, maybe we're not on the same track here. Right click the cell with the data. Select Format cells, then you will see a space which is called type: right in the center, here select the option which is called March 14, 2012, even though thats not the data you want. That should make it Mm/Dd/Yy.

Comment: Hey, I tried what you suggested above. I had to separate the date with delimiter "/" and used the datevalue() formula. It worked, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might need more control over it so I suggested that. If I answered your question successfully, don't forget to click the check mark to the left of my answer! It goes a long way to keeping us answerers around to help.